# Load vector drawable resource multiple times with glide issue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-glide

I am using glide 4.6.1 to load a Resource (a vector drawable). It's always the same resource but sometimes does not load properly. Looks Emily Blunt image.

The code:

```
fun AppCompatImageView.loadCircleImage(resId: Int, width: Int, height: Int) {
    val options = RequestOptions()
            .fitCenter()
            .override(width, height)
            .circleCrop()

    Glide.with(context)
            .load(AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, resId))
            .apply(options)
            .into(this)
}
```

[image: error glide]